# Ruby: What does module included in a method means?

Tags: ruby, module

I know that a module can be included in a class or another module.
But, I saw [here](http://codeshooter.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/including-and-extending-modules-in-ruby/#highlighter_98864) that a module is included **in a method**. What do this means ?

```
module ActsAsVotable

  module ClassMethods

    def acts_as_votable
      has_many :votes, :as => :votable, :dependent => :delete_all
      include InstanceMethods    # What does this means ??
    end

  end

  module InstanceMethods

    def cast_vote( vote )
      Vote.create( :votable => self, :up => vote == :up )
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the defined method is meant to be called at the class level, like this:

```
class Foo
    include ActsAsVotable
    acts_as_votable
end
```

Ruby has this wonderful/horrible (depends on who you ask) feature that you can dynamically define a class. Here, the `acts_as_votable` method first calls `has_many` (which adds a few mthods to the class `Foo`) and then adds the `cast_vote` method to the `Foo` class through the `include InstanceMethods`.

So, you end up with the equivalent of:

```
class Foo
   # Will add further methods.
   has_many :votes, :as => :votable, :dependent => :delete_all

   # include InstanceMethods
   def cast_vote( vote )
       Vote.create( :votable => self, :up => vote == :up )
   end
end
```

Comment: I thought that in Ruby a class can inherit only from other class, but I see in your code that a class inherits from a module: `class Foo < ActsAsVotable`. What does this means ?

Comment: Argh, you're correct. It should have been `class Foo ; include ActsAsVotable ; acts_as_votable ; end`. Have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Since the code you've quoted is for a Rails plugin I'm pretty sure there is some convention/magic that does the correct include for you. See [how it's supposed to be used](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/24/acts-as-voteable-rails-plugin/).

Comment: actually it should be class Foo; extend ActsAsVotable::ClassMethods; acts_as_votable; end;